# My application server side

Tags: android, server, server-side

I finished developing my client side application in Android.

I want to create a sign-up page and Page Login.

When the user login my app he selects several categories.
I want to show all the categories that users select a certain page. Please give me some tips for this. Do I need server side for this? If I do, where am I supposed to start? Thanks for help and sorry for weak English.

Comment: Please improve your question, right now it lacks context and it is too broad in scope.

Comment: If you want to store account data on a server then you'll need a server side. Wether the content / visuals of the page comes from the server or not (e.g. a native app using some RESTful signup API) is up to you.

Comment: My app displays of second-hand products, when the user selects a product he is interested in buying will have any awareness that people have posted. so I need a server side for this? I hope that now it is clearer

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to get the categories from the server, then this seems like something on the client side. In HTML, you can show a bunch of categories with < select >, which you can see here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

If you're doing it in an Android app, you can use [Spinner](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html).

Comment: That's exactly what I did. i used spinner...but I want to have displayed on all categories that users select.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What exactly is it that you are not able to do?